# How does wildcard mask really work?

Tags: wildcard, cisco

I'm studying for my cisco CCENT and I'm having a real hard time understanding wildcard masking this video was pretty straight forward and simple:

[Wildcard Mask Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lnq0NNcAyPw)

However when applied to this question it yields the wrong answer:

```
You need to create a wildcard mask for the entire Class B private IPv4 address space 
172.16.0.0/16 through 172.31.0.0/16. What is the wildcard mask?
```

One is tempted based upon the video to answer 0.0.255.255 however this is the incorrect answer with the correct answer being 0.15.255.255???

No matter how much I tinker with the bits to try and make sense of it I feel I am missing something can someone explain?

It occurs to me they could be super strict and only want the wildcard mask for the given range but in which case I would answer 2^5 for 32 = 255.248.0.0 = WCM 0.7.255.255 but alas this was not the answer either not even close what am I missing?

Here is another similar question...

```
Which address and wildcard mask combination will match all IPv4 addresses in the networks 
192.168.0.0/24 through 192.168.63.0/24?
```

What I wanted to say: 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255

Answer: 192.168.0.0 0.0.63.255

Answer (score 2):

Create an IP Slide Rule with the mask on the first row and the bit values on the second row.
  Mask  128 192 224 240 248 252 254 255
        128 64  32  16  8   4   2   1

Now you need to convert the IP address to binary
I hope my paste doesn't go funky. Here are the examples

Mask  128 192 224 240 248 252 254 255
        128 64  32  16  8   4   2   1 
192.168.0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00000000
192.168.0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1.00000000  x.x=192.168 since they are the same

Now you need to find from the IP slide rule the last bit where they are identical.
In this case it is the 64 and the mask for 64 is 192. Now you will subtract the new mask from 255

255 255 255 255
255 255 192 0   =
  0.  0. 63.255 Wildcard mask is 0.0.63.255  answer is 192.168.0.0 0.0.63.255

You need to create a wildcard mask for the entire Class B private IPv4 address space 
172.16.0.0/16 through 172.31.0.0/16. What is the wildcard mask?
Answer 0.15.255.255

Mask 128 192 224 240 248 252 254 255
     128 64  32  16  8   4   2   1
172. 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0.0
172. 0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0.0

Now you need to find in the ip slide rule the last bit where they are identical.
In this case it is the 16 and the mask for 16 is 240. Now you will subtract the new mask from 255

255 255 255 255
255 240 0   0
  0. 15.255.255 Wildcard mask is 0.15.255.255 answer is 172.0.0.0 0.15.255.255

Answer (score -1):

Results of the wildcard mask calculation provide the first IP address and last IP address in the wildcard mask network range.
If it was only 192.168.0.0 /24 your output would be 0.0.0.255 but your question is combination of 192.168.0.0/24 through 192.168.63.0/24 so you must calculate it.